# Vector of Pure Functions

Tags: vector, pure-function

I'm trying to make a function that takes in a vector of pure functions (representing a parametric equation) and returns another vector of pure functions representing an offset curve. Here's what I have as an example of an input curve:

```
HermiteSpline[{p1x_, p1y_}, {p2x_, p2y_}, {t1x_, t1y_}, {t2x_, t2y_}] :=
{p2x (3 #^2 - 2 #^3) + p1x (1 - 3 #^2 + 2 #^3) + (# - 2 #^2 + #^3) t1x + 
(-#^2 + #^3) t2x , p2y (3 #^2 - 2 #^3) + p1y (1 - 3 #^2 + 2 #^3) + (# - 
   2 #^2 + #^3) t1y + (-#^2 + #^3) t2y } &
```

Basically, some messy function that returns a vector with two elements, both pure functions. Then, I want to make another function that would take this as an argument and do some operations on the curve and return a different curve, like so:

```
CurveOffset[P_ , radius_] :=  radius {(P[[2]])'[#], (P[[1]])'[#]}/
Sqrt[((P[[1]])'[#])^2 + ((P[[2]])'[#])^2] &
```

So `P` would be the argument containing the function, it gets indexed and had its derivative taken, then returns another vector. But I keep getting the following error:

```
Part::partw: Part 2 of {0.5 (3 Slot[<<1>>]^2-2 Power[<<2>>])+0.2 (1-3 Power[<<2>>]+2 Slot[<<1>>]^3)+(#1-2 Power[<<2>>]+#1^3) 0+(-Slot[<<1>>]^2+#1^3) 0,0.5 (3 Slot[<<1>>]^2-2 Power[<<2>>])+0 (1-3 Power[<<2>>]+2 Slot[<<1>>]^3)+(#1-2 Power[<<2>>]+#1^3) 1+(-Slot[<<1>>]^2+#1^3) 1}& does not exist.
```

I've been searching around but I'm just not sure what's going wrong or how to fix it. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: try `hermiteSpline[{p1x_, p1y_}, {p2x_, p2y_}, {t1x_, t1y_}, {t2x_, 
   t2y_}] := {p2x (3 #^2 - 2 #^3) + 
    p1x (1 - 3 #^2 + 2 #^3) + (# - 
       2 #^2 + #^3) t1x + (-#^2 + #^3) t2x &, 
  p2y (3 #^2 - 2 #^3) + 
    p1y (1 - 3 #^2 + 2 #^3) + (# - 
       2 #^2 + #^3) t1y + (-#^2 + #^3) t2y &}`?

Comment: Just tried - then `CurveOffset` works okay, but then when I try something like `HermiteSpline[{0.2, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}][0]` which I would want when trying to plot ( like `ParametricPlot[HermiteSpline[{0.2, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}][t], {t, 0, 1}] `], it doesn't substitute the variable (I get something like `{0.5 (3 #1^2 - 2 #1^3) + 0.2 (1 - 3 #1^2 + 2 #1^3) + (#1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3) 0 + (-#1^2 + #1^3) 0 &, 0.5 (3 #1^2 - 2 #1^3) + 0 (1 - 3 #1^2 + 2 #1^3) + (#1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3) 1 + (-#1^2 + #1^3) 1 &}[0]`).

Comment: with `hermiteSpline` you should use `Through`; i.e. `ParametricPlot[
 Through@hermiteSpline[{0.2, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}][t], {t, 
  0, 1}]` and `Through@hermiteSpline[{0.2, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}][0]` gives `{0.2, 0.}`.

Comment: works, thank you!

Comment: Billy K, welcome to mma.se. I posted the comment as an answer.

Comment: Your formula for the offset is missing a minus sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `hermiteSpline` to return a pair of pure functions:

```
hermiteSpline[{p1x_, p1y_}, {p2x_, p2y_}, {t1x_, t1y_}, {t2x_, t2y_}] :=
Function/@ {p2x (3 #^2 - 2 #^3) + p1x (1 - 3 #^2 + 2 #^3) + (# - 2 #^2 + #^3) t1x + 
 (-#^2 + #^3) t2x , 
 p2y (3 #^2 - 2 #^3) + p1y (1 - 3 #^2 + 2 #^3) + (# -2 #^2 + #^3) t1y + (-#^2 + #^3) t2y }
```

or, equivalently,

```
 hermiteSpline[{p1x_, p1y_}, {p2x_, p2y_}, {t1x_, t1y_}, {t2x_, t2y_}] :=
  {p2x(3 #^2 - 2 #^3) + t1x(# - 2 #^2 + #^3) + t2x(-#^2 + #^3) + p1x (1 - 3 #^2 + 2 #^3)&, 
   p2y(3 #^2 - 2 #^3) + t1y(# - 2 #^2 + #^3) + t2y(-#^2 + #^3) + p1y (1 - 3 #^2 + 2 #^3)&}

Through@hermiteSpline[{0.2, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}][0]
```

> {0.2, 0.}

```
 ParametricPlot[Through@hermiteSpline[{0.2, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}][t], 
  {t,  0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 CurveOffset[hermiteSpline[{0.2, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}], radius] /@ {0, 1, 2}
```

> {{1. radius, 0.}, {1. radius, 0.},{0.889288 radius, -0.457348 radius}}

Comment: FWIW, the example Hermite spline is most easily implemented using `Interpolation[]`: `hs = Interpolation[{{{0}, {0.2, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0, 1}}}]; ParametricPlot[hs[t], {t, 0, 1}]` Then, if the parallel curves are wanted: `ParametricPlot[{hs[t] - (1/20) Normalize[Cross[hs'[t]]], hs[t], hs[t] + (1/20) Normalize[Cross[hs'[t]]]}, {t, 0, 1}]`.